# How to add comma at the end of line in 3 GB text file?

Tags: json, text, dataset, notepad++

I have a dataset of 3GB named with .json extension. I want to add comma at the end of each line except last one to validate JSON file and import in excel. Notepad++ donot support huge file.

I have tried to add comma programmatically it worked very well on small files but not on large one. I also tried 010 Editor,UltraEdit,Sublime Text but nothing helped.
**Need to replace this :**

```
{
  "tweet_id": "3600118565656676",  
  "tweet_city": "mansfield-engj9-gb", 
  "tweet_latitude": "53.130483", 
  "tweet_longitude": "-1.141419"
}
```

**with :**

```
{  
  "tweet_id": "3600118565656676", 
  "tweet_city": "mansfield-engj9-gb", 
  "tweet_latitude": "53.130483", 
  "tweet_longitude": "-1.141419"
},
```

Comment: what you mean by it didn't work did the program crash?

Comment: It worked well for 1.38MB text file but when i tried on 3GB text file then its not responding and i have waited for almost 6 hours but nothing happend

Comment: My issue is solved by using find and replace on Sublime text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=})(?!\s*,)`
- Replace with: `,`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=        # positive lookbehind, make sure we have before:
  }         # closing curly brace
)           # end lookbehind
(?!         # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
  \s*,      # 0 or more space and a comma
)           # end lookbehind
```